# Is it wrong to add css style class to jquery for convenience in the process of selecting?

Tags: jquery, web-frontend

I understand that *jQuery* provides various selectors.

However, selecting components seems so hierarchical sometimes.

When my view changes, I have to revise the *jQuery* selector I set.

I think that adding fake style class can help select components easily and  minimize revising code when view changes.

Is adding fake style class frequently used in front-end development?

If so, can I get some example situations?

Comment: As a term you made up, can you at least example what you mean with a "fake style class"? Maybe show an example?

Comment: An element has a class. It doesn't belong to the css, the css just uses it. The JS therefore can also just use it. There is nothing wrong with doing this. Like the answer below says, it can be useful to add a prefix if you want to know what it's for, exactly.

Comment: @Cal Irvine Thank you very much, that's what I exactly wanted to know!

Comment: @chytonpide https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class here's the details on the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked with dev's who preclude selector classes with `js` so you know it's not a class used for styling but for convenient access by JS.

Adding `js-` does not mean you cannot reference it in your css. It's essentially a naming convention for humans to identify what that class is there for - in this case javascript.

Example (Although I'm not sure why you need one it's the same as a class used in CSS for styling)

```
<div class='js-some-class'></div>
```

Selector:

```
$('.js-some-class')
```

Comment: There are no *css* classes or *js* classes.... just classes

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I think in the context of this question it's obvious what I'm referring to

Comment: @IsaacVidrine There are classes that exist *only* so that JS can select them. That's what Sean is referring to as a JS-class. They don't actually style anything specifically (unless you want to) but might be used to inject a style later.

Comment: @SeanT I agree with you. Your use of the terms css class and js class here have a clear purpose. Maybe just add an edit to explain a bit further.

Comment: Usually prefixing is my preferred approach too. It is easier to identify and seems fairly easy to maintain :D

Comment: The problem with this approach is similar to the problem posed in the question--if something changes with regard to usage the class name is now obsolete. Class names should be semantic, describing what they do, not describing what uses them.

Comment: @isherwood It is describing what it does though, it's saying it's used as a javascript selector. What you put after the pre-fix can say further details.